# Form Validation / Rules

Tags: jquery

I have a an text input that is enabled only when there has been a selection made from it's preceding select form element. I have managed to get this to work. However, I need to modify this so that if the text input is clicked prior to having made the required selection noted above, I would like my diaolog to fade in. Below is what I have so far, but does not seem to be working.

```
<script>
      $(document).ajaxSuccess(function () {
          $("#req").change(function () {
              $("#email").removeAttr('disabled')
          });


      if ($("#email").attr("disabled")) {
          $("#email").click(function() {
            $(".select_contact_dialog").show(800)
          })
      }
      else {
          $(".select_contact_dialog").hide();
      }
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle ? Because I your question is not clear

Comment: have you tried putting your script in doc ready function?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KnZwe/3/

Comment: I use the doc ready function in the above JS fiddle, but the actual application this form is loaded asynchronously and I've found I need the .ajaxSuccess.